# how to make a JDialog frameless?

Tags: java, frame, jdialog

my dialog example as following:

```
public class DialogNotify extends JDialog{
   public DialogNotify() {
      setModal(true);
      setSize(200, 100);
      setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

how to make it shown frameless ? by frameless, I mean with "close" button on top right or menu bar on top left.

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog entry on the topic: [Making a Custom Frameless Window](https://web.archive.org/web/20170510191837/http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/2005/09/making-a-custom-frameless-window/)

The key thing is to call `JDialog::setUndecorated(true)` to suppress the frame and titlebar.  You can do the same thing on a `JFrame`.

The call should be made when the dialog or frame's window is not displayed.

Comment: I have done this to remove the decoration from a JDialog, but all my windows are undecorated now! I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Anyone have seen this bug?